# Cypher no loops, no double paths

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am currently modelling a database with over 50.000 nodes and every node has 2 directed relationships. I try to get all nodes for one input node (the root node), which are connected to it with one relationship and all so-called children of these nodes and so on, until every node connected direct and indirect to this root node is reached.

```
String query =
  "MATCH (m {title:{title},namespaceID:{namespaceID}})-[:categorieLinkTo*..]->(n) " +
  "RETURN DISTINCT n.title AS Title, n.namespaceID " + 
  "ORDER BY n.title";

Result result = db.execute(query, params);
String infos = result.resultAsString();
```

I have read that the runtime is more likely in O(n^x), but I cannot find any command that excludes for example loops or multiple paths to one node, so the query takes simple over 2 hours and that is not acceptable for my use case.

Comment: There is no `GROUP BY` operator in Cypher. Did you mean `ORDER BY`?

Comment: Hey, yes my bad. That was just a try if something like that worked here.. and i forget to remove that . It didnt wokred with ORDER BY as well.

Answer (score 2):

For simple relationship expressions, Cypher excludes multiple relationships automatically by enforcing [uniqueness](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/#cypherdoc-uniqueness):

> While pattern matching, Neo4j makes sure to not include matches where the same graph relationship is found multiple times in a single pattern.

The documentation is not entirely clear on whether this works for variable length paths - so let's design a small experiment to confirm it:

```
CREATE
  (n1:Node {name: "n1"}),
  (n2:Node {name: "n2"}),
  (n3:Node {name: "n3"}),
  (n4:Node {name: "n4"}),
  (n1)-[:REL]->(n2),
  (n2)-[:REL]->(n3),
  (n3)-[:REL]->(n2),
  (n2)-[:REL]->(n4)
```

This results in the following graph:

[image]

Query with:

```
MATCH (n:Node {name:"n1"})-[:REL*..]->(m)
RETURN m
```

The result is:

```
╒══════════╕
│m         │
╞══════════╡
│{name: n2}│
├──────────┤
│{name: n3}│
├──────────┤
│{name: n2}│
├──────────┤
│{name: n4}│
├──────────┤
│{name: n4}│
└──────────┘
```

As you can see `n4` is included multiple times (as it can be accessed with avoiding the loop and going through the loop as well). 
Check the execution with `PROFILE`:

[image]

So we should use `DISTINCT` to get rid of the duplicates:

```
MATCH (n:Node {name:"n1"})-[:REL*..]->(m)
RETURN DISTINCT m
```

The result is:

```
╒══════════╕
│m         │
╞══════════╡
│{name: n2}│
├──────────┤
│{name: n3}│
├──────────┤
│{name: n4}│
└──────────┘
```

Again, check the execution with `PROFILE`:

[image]

Comment: The result at least in my query, when i reduce the depth to e.g. 6 there are multiple times the same node.

Comment: When i remove the distinct there are multiple times the same node.. so the query takes simple ages.

Comment: You're correct, I worked a bit on the experiment and updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Btw, after the query finishes (in 2 hours), how many nodes do you get?

Comment: Thank you  for your help.The result is nearly half the complete Graph, around 25.000 nodes. If i could find an expression that cypher would only expnad every node only once, i guess it will get way faster.

Answer (score 1):

There are certainly some things we can do to improve this query.

For one, you aren't using labels at all. And because you aren't using labels, your match on the input node can't take advantage of any schema indexes you may have in place, and it must do a scan of all 50k nodes accessing and comparing properties until it finds every one with the given title and namespace (it will not stop when it's found one, as it does not know if there are other nodes that satisfy the conditions). You can check the timing by matching on the start node alone.

To improve this, your nodes should be labeled, and your match on your start node should include the label, and your title and namespaceID properties should be indexed.

That alone should provide a noticeable improvement in query speed.

The next question is if the remaining bottleneck is more due to the sorting, or returning a massive result set?

You can check the cost for sorting alone by LIMITing the results you return.

You can use this for the end of the query, after the match.

```
WITH DISTINCT n
ORDER BY n.title
LIMIT 10
RETURN n.title AS Title, n.namespaceID 
ORDER BY n.title
```

Also, when doing any performance tuning, you should PROFILE your queries (at least the ones that finish in a reasonable amount of time) and EXPLAIN the ones that are taking an absurd amount of time to examine the query plan.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I used limit up to 10 (moore in the way of [:categorieLinkTo*..10] but i think it is the same and without distinct i got over 55.000 Nodes back. All my Nodes are Labeld but they all remain to the same Label (because the Database will become way bigger later on..), so the main Problem is, that the query dosnt realise, that it allready visited some Nodes. But i am working on a simple BFS myself now because Cypher dose not offer anything useful here.

Comment: LIMIT 10 is different in that it will only return 10 results back total. The suggestion was to test whether the query is inefficient only because of the massive number of rows returned (returning so many doesn't seem to make sense) or if there are other major inefficiencies also causing massive slowdown, which I think there are.

Comment: And again, you need labels in your query if you plan on using your indexes to find your start node. As it stands now it's doing a complete graph scan and property comparison on all 55k nodes JUST to find the node(s) to start the rest of your query. You can test this by seeing how long this takes to execute: `MATCH (m {title:{title},namespaceID:{namespaceID}})` You can try PROFILEing it as well

Answer (score 0):

```
public static HashSet<Node> breadthFirst(String name, int namespace, GraphDatabaseService db) {

        // Hashmap for storing the cypher query and its parameters
        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();


        // Adding the title and namespaceID as parameters to the Hashmap
        params.put("title", name);
        params.put("namespaceID", namespace);

        /*it is a simple BFS with these variables below
         * basically a Queue (touched) as usual, a Set to store the nodes
         *  which have been used (finished), a return variable and 2 result
         *  variables for the queries
         */
        Node startNode = null;
        String query = "Match (n{title:{title},namespaceID:{namespaceID}})-[:categorieLinkTo]-> (m) RETURN m";
        Queue<Node> touched = new LinkedList<Node>();
        HashSet<Node>finished = new HashSet<Node>();
        HashSet<Node> returnResult = new  HashSet<Node>();

        Result iniResult = null;
        Result tempResult=null;

        /*the part below get the direct nodes and puts them
         * into the queue
         */
            try (Transaction tx = db.beginTx()) {
                 iniResult =db.execute(query,params);


                while(iniResult.hasNext()){
                  Map<String,Object> iniNode=iniResult.next();
                  startNode=(Node) iniNode.get("m");
                  touched.add(startNode);
                  finished.add(startNode);
                }
                tx.success();
                }catch (QueryExecutionException e) {
                logger.error("Fehler bei Ausführung der Anfrage", e);  
                }

            /*and now we just execute the BFS (don't think i need more to
             * say here.. we are all pros ;))
             * as usual, marking every node we have visited
             * and saving every visited node.
             * the difficult part had been the casting from
             * and to node and result, everything else is pretty much
             * straightforward. I think the  variables explain their self
             * via their name....
             */

               while(! (touched.isEmpty())){
                 try (Transaction tx = db.beginTx()) {
                   Node currNode=touched.poll();
                   returnResult.add(currNode);

                   tempResult=null;               
                   Map<String, Object> paramsTemp = new HashMap<>();
                   paramsTemp.put("title",currNode.getProperty("title").toString());
                   paramsTemp.put("namespaceID", 14);
                   String tempQuery = "MATCH (n{title:{title},namespaceID:{namespaceID}})-[:categorieLinkTo] -> (m) RETURN m";
                   tempResult =  db.execute(tempQuery,paramsTemp);



                 while(tempResult.hasNext()){
                     Map<String, Object> currResult= null;
                     currResult=tempResult.next();
                     Node tempCurrNode = (Node) currResult.get("m");

                     if (!finished.contains(tempCurrNode)){
                         touched.add(tempCurrNode);
                         finished.add(tempCurrNode);


                     }


                  }


               tx.success();  
            }catch (QueryExecutionException f) {
                logger.error("Fehler bei Ausführung der Anfrage", f);
            }
        }       


        return returnResult;

}
```

Since I was not able to find a fitting Cypher expression, I just wrote a pretty BFS myself - it works it seems.